# Make payment with Paypal-Python-SDK

Tags: python, paypal

I want to use the Paypal SDK with Python Flask to implement payments with the Paypal method (paypal to paypal, no Visa card or something). I'm trying to understand how things work, and I've got a little problem.

1. First, configure the SDK. Done and understood
2. Then, create a payment URL and redirect the user to it. [Done and understood](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK/blob/master/samples/payment/create_with_paypal.py)
3. Finally, check if the user sent the money. [Undone and not understood](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK#execute-payment)

   ```
   payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment.find("PAY-57363176S1057143SKE2HO3A")
   ```

What is `PAY-57363176S1057143SKE2HO3A`? Is that the `payment.id` seen in *2.* line 51? If yes, then, what is `{"payer_id": "DUFRQ8GWYMJXC"}`? There's in this code 2 IDs, and the only reference to an ID in the `create_with_paypal.py` file is the single `payment.id`.

Could someone help me, please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are separate identifiers for the payment and for the party (person or company) which is contributing money in that payment. So if foo@bar.com sends henry13@somesite.com $10, that movement of funds between the two payers has a payment ID which you would use to retrieve information about the payment. The transaction information will include what parties sent and received money in the payment, and the sender (payer)'s account ID is what is being called the payer ID.

Comment: Alright thanks, now I understand. But, how do I get the _payer ID_ with just a _payment ID_ ? Will I have to use [this](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK#get-payment-details) ?

Comment: Can't edit, but it looks like the payer ID is sent to the "return URL" I provided in the `create_with_paypal.py` file.

Comment: There are multiple ways to get the payer ID. But yes, the first/fastest way is in the redirect back to your site.The payer has just identified themselves to PayPal (usually by logging in) so this is the first time PayPal can give you this info. Once the payment is made, the payer's identity is also permanantly a part of the payment information, so can be retrieved by APIs that access the payment.

Answer (score 0):

## Card Payment with Paypal

## step-1 Add card Details

```
    from paypalrestsdk import CreditCard
    from paypalrestsdk import Payment

    def card_payemnt(request):
        paypalrestsdk.configure({
            "mode": "sandbox",  # sandbox or live
            'client_id' :"",
            'client_secret':"",
        })

        credit_card = CreditCard({
            "type": "visa",
            "number": "4024007185826731",
            "expire_month": "12",
            "expire_year": "2022",
            "cvv2": "874",
            "first_name": "Joe",
            "last_name": "Shopper",
        })

        if credit_card.create():
            print("CreditCard[%s] created successfully" % (credit_card.id ))
            return HttpResponse('good')
        else:
            print("Error while creating CreditCard:")
            print(credit_card.error)
```

## step2 Complete Payment by using Card ID

```
        def credit_card_payment(request):
            paypalrestsdk.configure({
                "mode": "sandbox",  # sandbox or live
                'client_id': "",
                'client_secret': "",
            })
            payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment(
                {
                    "intent": "sale",
                    "payer": {
                        "payment_method": "credit_card",
                        "funding_instruments": [
                            {
                                "credit_card_token": {
                                    "credit_card_id": "CARD-7MH68586JW7132142LXWASJI",

                                }
                            }]
                    },
                    "transactions": [
                        {
                            "amount": {
                                "total": "6.70",
                                "currency": "USD"
                            },
                            "description": "Payment by vaulted credit card."
                        }]
                }
            )
            if payment.create():
                print(payment.id)

                print("Payment created successfully")
            else:
                print(payment.error)
```